# Create Data Validation in Excel Sheet

Tags: excel, validation, excel-formula

I have a data validation issue.

My cell reference should be 2 letters then 4 digits then 1 letter

As Example - AB1234A, xY0123z

Need to consider Both simple and Capital as well. Other way of input need to reject.
[image: Snap Shot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use custom validation formula for that cell.
Check if first 2 are letters with `ISTEXT` and `LEFT` formulas. If 3rd, 4th, 5th and 5th are numbers with `ISNUMBER` and `MID` formulas, check if length is 7 symbols with `LEN` and so on. Wrap everything with `AND`

And you will get something like this:

```
=AND(LEN(C4)=7,ISTEXT(LEFT(C4,2)),ISNUMBER(VALUE(MID(C4,3,4))),ISNUMBER(RIGHT(C4,1)+1)=FALSE)
```

(Note that if you extract 1 symbol with `LEFT`, `RIGHT` or `MID`and it is a number it will be treated like text. Workaround is to add any number and check if it converts to a number (adding number to actual text would give value error)